# update map dircetions in android after specific time?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working on an android map app.I am getting direction from latitude and longitude.
But the problem is this i want to update map directions after some time or after location change.
My code is below can any one help me in this.

```
       Button.OnClickListener addressclick = new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                /*TextView tv = (TextView)v;
                String latitude ="0";
                String longitude = "0";
                String label = "Location";
                String uriBegin = "geo:" + latitude + "," + longitude;
                String query = tv.getText().toString() + "(" + label + ")";
                String encodedQuery = Uri.encode(query);
                String uriString = uriBegin + "?q=" + encodedQuery+"&z=10";
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);*/ 
                TextView tv = (TextView)v;                  
                String addressStr = tv.getText().toString();
                  Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(context);

                  try {
                      List<Address> addresses =
                  geoCoder.getFromLocationName(addressStr, 1); 
                      if (addresses.size() >  0) {
                         latitude = addresses.get(0).getLatitude(); 
                         longitude =addresses.get(0).getLongitude(); }

                  } catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                String directionweburl = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+Double.toString(latitude)+","+Double.toString(longitude)+"&saddr="+Double.toString(currentlat)+","+Double.toString(currentlong);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(directionweburl));
                myIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }


        };
```

what am i missing here?anyone can tell?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start a service and put regular check in it. After some time, you can update map directions or check current location in order to update location info.